# cannot pass array to php file via ajax request (jquery)

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to pass a serialzed array via ajax request to my saveData.php file in order to save the data into my database.

```
var postData = $('#formular').serializeArray();
```

this is the Data I want to pass.
I am creating an array with all the data in order to pass it as a json-Array to the php file:

```
    var formArray={};
    $.each(postData, function (index, field ){
        formArray[field.name]=field.value;
    });
    var formData=JSON.stringify(formArray);

$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url:"functions/saveData.php",
        data : formData,
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log('done: '+data);
    }).fail(function(data) {
        console.log('fail: '+data);         
    });
```

When I look at the $_POST in PHP, there is an emty array ...

on the php side I try to catch the data with the following code....

```
$getPostedData=$_POST;

if($debug){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($getPostedData);
    echo'</pre>';
}
```

This gives me the following Output:

```
    Array
(
)
```

what am I doing wrong?
Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple example, which similar to your case. It's enough to use `serialize()`:

```
var postData = $('#formular').serialize();
```

And now you can simply send it to AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
   url:"functions/saveData.php", 
   method:"POST",
   data: postData
}).done(function(resp){
   console.log(resp);
});
```

HTML code form looks like next:

```
<form id="formular" onsubmit="javascript:return false;">
    <!-- for defined data -->
    <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="3435" /> 

    <!-- for arrays -->
    <input type="text" name="ex_arr[]" value="3343" />
    <input type="text" name="ex_arr[]" value="1123" />

</form>
```

Comment: Concatenation `console.log('done: '+data);` means `string` + `array/object`. Do just `console.log(data);`. Also, present your HTML form.

Comment: @ccalbow, you're welcome) never forget datatypes of input/output variables

Comment: the problem was not the output format, but the empty output... now it gives me all the data I needed in the php array. It is full of data now. one of the problems was the content type. I deleted it and now it works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah, if you don't need to send files to the PHP, it's enough to use these 3 lines, nothing else.